# Apply Format to a certain textpattern in In Design

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep

I have an insane list:

```
 Roti Flue  #   748 **
 Wassberg   #   748 **
 Furtbüel   #   741 **
 Zimberg        #   738 **
 Born       #   719 **
 + 6000 entries
```

Now Id like to apply a text format to the numbers. Is it possible to create a filter to search for this pattern and apply a stile? I tought something like GREP:

[image]

But this doesn't work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful with the spaces, this is the working **GREP**:

```
(?<=\#\s{3})\d+(?=\s\*{2})
```

- Behind the # there are three spaces: `\s{3}`
- Before the * there is a space: `\s`

You can not apply a paragraph style to a text inside a paragraph. Instead, apply a text format:

[image: grep 01]

Or better create a **GREP Style** inside the **Paragraph Style**:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Yep i wanted to apply a grep style. Didn't know the english name.

Comment: you may wish to disable dithering wen capturing the dialogs

Comment: Better still (because it’s less processor-intensive and won’t slow down your InDesign if you have lots of paragraphs), use nested styles. Apply none up to and including #, then apply your style up to (but not including) *, and Robert is the husband of your parent’s sibling.